# Is there something funny with async OnNavigatedTo?

Tags: c#, windows-8

I have two pages; `MainPage` and `SettingsPage`.

In MainPage, in its `OnNavigatedTo` method I check some isolated storage and if it does not match I want the app to navigated to `SettingsPage`.

`OnNavigatedTo` is marked `async` since I'm using awaited methods to check up on a variable. What works is that it reads the variable and reports that it needs to navigate, so I call

```
this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(SettingsPage));
```

No errors is being thrown. But 70%++ of the time I call this Navigate method it does nothing! Is the way of navigating between pages different from Windows Phone? I'm doing the exact same thing there, but using URLs instead of `typeof(XXXPage)`

What gives? It seems to not follow the `async` flag, since it some times manages to navigate to the SettingsPage... but 70%+ of the times the it seems that the application ignores the `async OnNavigatedTo` and runs the application synchronously.

I've placed a Debug.WriteLine on the navigation event, and it calls `Navigate(typeof(SettingsPage))` each time... but seems to fail somewhere?

Comment: Does it navigate without the async?

Comment: No... But what I observed now that App.xaml.cs's OnLaunched: Window.Current.Activate() is called AFTER the navigation? Isnt the the app "active" when it brings up the first page and I call Navigation in  OnNavigatedTo?

Comment: I'm using MVVM by the way.

Comment: Apart from scheduling on a dispatcher, you may also consider Navigating in `Loaded` event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've encountered this same behavior. Queue the new navigation at a low priority to give the first page load and app initialization a chance to fully complete.

```
public async virtual Task NavigateAsync(Type sourcePageType)
{
    await Window.Current.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Low, () =>
        {
            ((Frame)Window.Current.Content).Navigate(sourcePageType);
        });
}
```

Comment: It seems to navigate 100% of the times now, instead of <30%! But It feels a bit hacky... the problem here is that App isn't finished loading before I call navigation to other pages? Couldnt I rearrange App.xaml.cs to listen to activation complete or anything and then load the application?

Comment: Ive never gotten to the bottom of it but this is the only way I've ever safely redirected navigation while things are bootstrapping. I suppose you could make the choice to redirect at some later point but I think you'll find it even hackier (though I don't think this async approach is at all hack, it just says 'hey when you're done doing what you're doing right now, go to this page' which is a perfectly reasonable thing to ask an app to do). Plus it's worked for me since WP7.